# Can't get Organization Name from AD

Tags: javascript, column, jsom, ad

Good day,

I have a question with getting user profile data from AD by JavaScript for SharePoint Display Form. I can get user Department by script:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="SP.UserProfiles.js" runat="server"
    ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
…
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
       $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.UserProfiles.js", getUserProperties);
    });
…
function getUserProperties() {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
        personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
        context.load(personProperties);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
    }

function onRequestSuccess() {
    console.log(personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department']);
     persDepartment=personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
}
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Error');
}
```

I would like to get user organization name (or Employer name) from AD. But
`persDepartment=personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()[Organization];`
didn’t help.

Could you tell me how I can get Organization name?

Would be grateful for info.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the properties from the [User Profile Service Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/user-profile-service-overview), not directly from Active Directory.

In order to retrieve a property you will first have to make sure that it is synchronized. Organization is not one of the standard properties that is synced I believe.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I make Organization to sync up?

Comment: What SharePoint version is this?

Comment: Sharepoint 2016

Comment: Check the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/add-edit-or-delete-custom-properties-for-a-user-profile). There is a step-by-step guide. Point 16 and 17 tells you how to set up the sync once you have created the property.

Comment: I im adding New Organization property. Point 16. In the Property Mapping for Synchronization section I see "No elements for displaying in this view". Point 17 - I can't specify the source data connection, attribute, and synchronization direction for the mapping because I don't see any attributes...

Comment: You might want to save the new property first, then go back to edit it afterwards to add the mapping

Comment: I saved, go back. Nothing changed...

Comment: Make sure that your account has the permissions mentioned here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/ee721057(v=office.14)

Comment: I use Farm Admin account

Comment: Still, verify that the account has "Full Control" on the service application as mentioned in the link. The user profile service application is full of strange config settings that needs to be right for everything to work as expected.

Comment: Yes, account has "Full Control'

Comment: The question is still actual

Comment: So are the links and recommendations provided, without you providing any more details it is hard to give you any more advise. Again - go back to the step-by-step guide and be sure that all requirements and prerequisites are met. then follow each step to the letter. If anything goes wrong in the process, report back with a full copy of any error message...

Comment: I provided step-by-step all recomendations, created Organization property by "Full control" Farm admin account.

Comment: Type: string, selected Configure a Term Set to be used for this property, selected the Default User Profile Subtype, Policy Settings replicated, Edit Settings disabled, Display Settings - Show in profile properties section on user profile page,Show on the Edit Details page. Search Settings: Alias, Indexed, Property Mapping for Synchronization I set Organization attribute, import direction, source - my server connection.

Comment: After full replication Organization property doesn't display in User Profile. I filled Organization property for my profile in User Profile Management and I can see Organization value in my profile. But I can't understand why replication didn't fill Organization after User Profile replication. Another User profile propertyes (location, department) filled successfully.

Comment: I set Company attribute in Property Mapping for Synchronization. And Organization was set  after User Profile replication. Thanks for your help!